# Applying Boundary Conditions to Keras Output

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, keras

I have a periodic value (an angle) with period = `pi` (i.e. `pi+a` = `a`). I am training a neural network in Keras to output this value, given a set of inputs. The network performs very well, except for at the boundaries `0` and `pi` (if the truth value is `0` or `pi`, its prediction is random). This can be seen in [this histogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2SUT.png). Does anyone know why that is? Can I somehow include the boundaries in the training or tell it that if it predicts `pi+a`, when the truth value is `a`, then it predicted correctly and doesn't need to update its weights and biases? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Neuronal networks do not perform well on a task where you have a non-continuous behavior in your data. Especially on The angular data like yours. To circumvent your problem, you can first do a trigonometric transformation of your target value. This is actually nothing but applying a kernel to your data. Let's say your periodic output data is `y=0...π`. Then your new target is a bi-valued vector `y_hat=[sin(2y), cos(2y)]`. Let your network train against `y_hat`, while you perform the back transformation `y=.5 atan2(y_hat)` during inference to get your original value.